# Spring data JDBC query creation with pagination complains IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: Incorrect result size

Tags: spring, pagination, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

I'm struggling to trying the pagination feature, as described in the [reference document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.special-parameters).
This is my table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE cities
(
    id      int PRIMARY KEY,
    name    varchar(255),
    pref_id int
);
```

Repository:

```
public interface CityRepository extends CrudRepository<CityEntity, Integer> {

  Page<CityEntity> findAll(Pageable pageable);

  // get all cities in the prefecture
  Page<CityEntity> findByPrefId(Integer prefId, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Test code:

```
Page<CityEntity> allCities = repository.findAll(PageRequest.of(0, 10));
Page<CityEntity> cities = repository.findByPrefId(1, PageRequest.of(0, 10));
```

`findAll` works well, but findByPrefId throws the following error:

```
Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 10
org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 10
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.nullableSingleResult(DataAccessUtils.java:100)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:237)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.query.AbstractJdbcQuery.lambda$singleObjectQuery$1(AbstractJdbcQuery.java:115)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.query.PartTreeJdbcQuery.execute(PartTreeJdbcQuery.java:98)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor$QueryMethodInvoker.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:195)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130)
...
```

If I change the method signature into `List<CityEntity> findByPrefId(Integer prefId, Pageable pageable)`, it works.

Am I missing something? I'm using the latest version of spring-data-jdbc (2.0.2.RELEASE).

Comment: Have you tried with   Page<CityEntity> findAllByPrefId(Integer prefId, Pageable pageable) instead of   Page<CityEntity> findByPrefId(Integer prefId, Pageable pageable);

Comment: Yes I have, but the result was the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about the technicality, but this is what I learned from experience.

In your case, if the total number of cities is lesser than the pageable.getPageSize(), then your repository will return a List<>.

But if total number of cities is bigger than the pageable.getPageSize() then your repository will return a Page<>.

Knowing that, this is what I did to work around it.

```
    Long amount = repository.countByPrefId(prefId);
    if(pagination.getPageSize()>amount ) {
       List<CityEntity> list = repository.findByPrefId(prefId);
    } else {
       Page<CityEntity> pages = repository.findByPrefId(person, PageRequest.of(0, 10));
    }
```

This also means that in your repository you'll have two differents methods, one with Pageable as a parameter and one with **only** PrefId as a parameter.

Comment: This answer is unhelpful. See @bonnarooster answer that explains a workaround and a link to the bug in the spring data jdbc project.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the accepted answer is referring to Spring Data JPA which does work by returning pages based on a count query derived from the custom query OR manually set via `countQuery`, no reason for the `if/else`.

However this flat out does not work in Spring Data JDBC.

https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC-554

Workaround provided in link but for reference:

```
    interface FooRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<FooEntity, Long> {
        List<FooEntity> findAllByBar(String bar, Pageable pageable);
        Long countAllByBar(String bar);
    }
```

And then combining those 2 queries like this:

```
    List<FooEntity> fooList = repository.findAllByBar("...", pageable);
    Long fooTotalCount = repository.countAllByBar("...");

    Page<FooEntity> fooPage = PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(fooList, pageable, () -> fooTotalCount);
```